# how can i use japanese google tts engine in my android app without change any device setting

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am developing a Japanese study app.
i wanna hear japanese pronunciation in my app.

i initialize tts like this

```
private TextToSpeech tts;

private void initTTS()
{
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status)
        {
            if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
            {
                Locale loc = new Locale("ja_JP");
                int result = tts.setLanguage(loc);
                if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED)
                {
                    Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                    installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    installIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    //installIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.tts");
                    startActivityForResult(installIntent,MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.e(TAG,"initilization success");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Log.e(TAG,"initilization failed");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

my phone's default language setting is not japanese. and my app users neither.

when default laguage setting is not japanese, tts.setLanguage return TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA. so i installed tts data with new activity. but google tts engine japanese already had been installed.
how can i provide japanese tts service to my client without change client's phone language.

Comment: there are two things that are different: 1) the phone's default language setting (this is what language all text show as in all apps), and 2) the phone's text-to-speech default language setting.  Your claim that "when default laguage setting is not japanese, tts.setLanguage return TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA." is not necessarily true for either case 1 or 2.  That error message is returned when the tts data is missing for the specific language requested (Locale loc = new Locale("ja_JP");) and has nothing to do with which language is currently selected as the tts default in settings.

Comment: LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED means that the tts on the user's phone cannot speak japanese -- so you cannot download it.  LANG_MISSING_DATA means that the language data is missing.  You are checking for both those things and responding with the same action which does not make sense.

Comment: That fact that japanese is included in the google speech engine does not clarify the problem or contrast with anything you said prior to that.

Comment: There is no reason why changing the desired locale on your tts and speaking would require changing "the client's phone language."

Comment: The google engine (recent versions) will automatically download and speak the required language without the need to go to device settings.  It only requires the user has internet.  I would recommend simply NOT checking for (MISSING_DATA || LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) and simply send the speak() request anyway.  Set an UtteranceProgressListener and if there is an error, then give the user an alert dialog explaining that they must install the google tts, then have the "OK" button send them to the play store to get the google engine.

Comment: thank you for your help. i found what is problem. my defualt "2) the phone's text-to-speech default language setting"  was not google tts engine. it was samsung tts engine. as your comment i changed tts engine frome samsung to google,and it was fixed. but i still have problem.

Comment: When it is not the Google tts engine, how can I automatically change to the Google tts engine

Comment: it means that i wish my client don't need to connect to phone's settings, change tts engine in my app. and use it.

Comment: It is assumed that the Google tts engine is installed but not the default.

Answer (score 1):

To initialize a TTS object that specifically uses the google engine regardless of the user's preferred engine settings:

```
private void createGoogleTTS() {

        googleTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    Log.i("XXX", "Google tts initialized");
                    onTTSInitialized();
                } else {
                    Log.i("XXX", "Internal Google engine init error.");
                }
            }
        }, "com.google.android.tts");

    }
```

Of course, this will only work if the google engine is installed, so you could also use these methods:

```
private boolean isGoogleTTSInstalled() {

        Intent ttsIntent = new Intent();
        ttsIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
        PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> listOfInstalledTTSInfo = pm.queryIntentActivities(ttsIntent, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        for (ResolveInfo r : listOfInstalledTTSInfo) {
            String engineName = r.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
            if (engineName.equals("com.google.android.tts")) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

private void installGoogleTTS() {

        Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                .setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.google.android.tts"));
        startActivity(goToMarket);

    }


// use this if attempting to speak in Japanese locale results in onError() being called by your UtteranceProgressListener.
private void openTTSSettingsToInstallUnsupportedLanguage() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.android.settings.TTS_SETTINGS");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```